# Function that returns all permutations

Tags: function, rust, permutation

I want to make a function to return all permutations of a sequence. I took an example from Rosetta Code and tried to write it in Rust, but it will not work. When I try to fix it I either cause an overflow or break it again. This code has an arithmetic overflow error:

```
fn permutations_(sequence: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    if sequence.len() == 0 {
        let x: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![]];
        return x
    }

    let mut result: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();

    for (i, item) in permutations_(to_vec(&sequence[0..sequence.len() - 1])).iter().enumerate() {

        let mut n = reverse(&(0..item.len() + 1).collect::<Vec<usize>>());

        if i % 2 != 0 {
            n = (0..item.len() + 1).collect::<Vec<usize>>();
        }

        for k in n {
            let mut items = Vec::new();

            for x in &item[0..k] {
                items.push(*x);
            }

            items.push(item[item.len() - 1]);

            for x in &item[k..item.len()] {
                items.push(*x);
            }

            result.push(items);
        }
    }

    result
}
```

If there is a better way to do this I would like to know, otherwise I need ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: You forgot to include the code for `to_vec` and `reverse`.

Comment: Which Rosetta Code snippet did you start from? None of the ones I have found seem to match your code at all. Checking if `i`is even / odd only occurs in a small handful (like Swift or Powershell), but those use a "swap" construct that you don't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [permutohedron](https://crates.io/crates/permutohedron/) crate which does what you want. Take a look at its [benchmarks](https://github.com/bluss/permutohedron/blob/master/benches/bench.rs) or [tests](https://github.com/bluss/permutohedron/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L168) to see how you can use it.

Basically you give a `&mut` of your data to the construction of a `Heap`, then you can call `next_permutation()` on it to get an `Option` of a mutable reference to the permuted data. It's an `Option` so that `None` can signal that there are no remaining permutations. Note that `Heap` also implements `Iterator`, so you can just use `for permutation in heap { ... }` as well.

Answer (score 3):

> This code has an arithmetic overflow error

If I make minimal changes (see below) to even get your code to compile, I get this error:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'arithmetic operation overflowed', <anon>:26
```

**Read** the error — it *tells you what line is causing the problem*. Looking at line 26, I see this:

```
items.push(item[item.len() - 1]);
```

Your `item.len()` is zero, and you are trying to subtract 1 from that. That causes a crash. Don't do that.

---

```
fn permutations_(sequence: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    if sequence.len() == 0 {
        let x: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![]];
        return x
    }

    let mut result: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();

    for (i, item) in permutations_(sequence[0..sequence.len() - 1].into()).iter().enumerate() {
        let mut n = (0..item.len() + 1).collect::<Vec<usize>>();
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            n.reverse();
        }

        for k in n {
            let mut items = Vec::new();

            for x in &item[0..k] {
                items.push(*x);
            }

            items.push(item[item.len() - 1]);

            for x in &item[k..item.len()] {
                items.push(*x);
            }

            result.push(items);
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", permutations_(vec![1]))
}
```